# Random module in python

Tags: python, time-complexity

How does the random module works in python (or any related/preferable language) ? Is there any way that we can actually write a random number generator by ourselves/What does the inner working of the random module looks like?

Do you think the time complexities varies for different functions like `randint()`, `randrange()`, and others? Or it is just that the time complexities varies between the functions mentioned above and for the methods like `random.choice()` ?

Answer (score 2):

There are many good articles on random number generators.  They're not hard to create, but it's very easy to create one that isn't really random.  The previous generation used "linear congruential" random number generators, where you just did a multiply, and addition, and a modulo operation.  Python today uses a "Mersenne twister" algorithm, which requires a bit more arithmetic, but has a very, very long sequence before repeating.

Almost all of the modules in `random` just grab the next 64-bit integer, and then do a simple conversion to produce `randint` or `randfloat`.  `choice`, it should be clear, just done one array lookup after picking the number.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation
https://www.howtogeek.com/183051/htg-explains-how-computers-generate-random-numbers/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister

Answer (score 0):

I have also very long wonder what could be the complexity of generating random numbers and it is not easy to find the answer on the internet.

I carried out my own experiment (the code ran in roughly 9min on my laptop intel vPRO i9 + 32Go RAM and required around 22Go). Here are the code and the results:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
from tqdm import tqdm

sizes = np.geomspace(1,1e9,100)

# instantiate resuls lists
list_times_create_random_randint_set = []
list_times_create_random_randint_size = []
list_times_create_random_rand = []
list_times_create_random_uniform = []
list_times_create_random_choice = []
list_times_compute_mean = []
list_times_compute_sqared_values = []
list_times_loop = []
list_times_instantiate_list = []

# run benchmark
for size in tqdm(sizes):
    # create a random generator to be sure the next step focuses on generation only
    rng = np.random.default_rng(datetime.now().microsecond)
    t1 = datetime.now()
    
    # step 1: generation randint with shape (10,) picked among the set of int [1, size]
    arr = np.random.randint(size,size=50)
    t2 = datetime.now()
    
    # step 2: generation randint with shape (size,) picked among the set of int [0, 50]
    np.random.randint(50,size=int(size))
    t3 = datetime.now()
    
    # step 3: generation of a random array with shape (size,)
    np.random.rand(int(size))
    t4 = datetime.now()
    
    # step 4: generation of uniform sample from intervalle (0,1) with shape (size,)
    arr = rng.uniform(0,1,int(size))
    t5 = datetime.now()
    
    # step 5: selection randomly one element with choice within arr 
    np.random.choice(arr, 1)
    t6 = datetime.now()
    
    # step 6: compute mean
    np.mean(arr)
    t7 = datetime.now()
    
    # step 7: compute squared array
    arr**2
    t8 = datetime.now()
    
    # step 8: loop on array without variable asignment
    for _ in arr:
        continue
    t9 = datetime.now()
    
    # step 9: instantiate a list
    list_ = [None] * int(size)
    t10 = datetime.now()

    list_times_create_random_randint_set.append((t2-t1).seconds*1000000+(t2-t1).microseconds)
    list_times_create_random_randint_size.append((t3-t2).seconds*1000000+(t3-t2).microseconds)
    list_times_create_random_rand.append((t4-t3).seconds*1000000+(t4-t3).microseconds)
    list_times_create_random_uniform.append((t5-t4).seconds*1000000+(t5-t4).microseconds)
    list_times_create_random_choice.append((t6-t5).seconds*1000000+(t6-t5).microseconds)
    list_times_compute_mean.append((t7-t6).seconds*1000000+(t7-t6).microseconds)
    list_times_compute_sqared_values.append((t8-t7).seconds*1000000+(t8-t7).microseconds)
    list_times_loop.append((t9-t8).seconds*1000000+(t9-t8).microseconds)
    list_times_instantiate_list.append((t10-t9).seconds*1000000+(t10-t9).microseconds)

plt.plot(sizes,list_times_create_random_randint_set,label='randint from [1,size] with shape (50,)')
plt.plot(sizes,list_times_create_random_randint_size,label='randint from [1,50] with shape (size,)')
plt.plot(sizes,list_times_create_random_rand,label='random array with shape (size,)')
plt.plot(sizes,list_times_create_random_uniform,label='uniform random array from (0,1) with shape (size,)')
plt.plot(sizes,list_times_create_random_choice,label='pick randomly 1 value from array with shape (size,)')
plt.plot(sizes,list_times_compute_mean,label='compute mean')
plt.plot(sizes,list_times_compute_sqared_values,label='compute sqared array')
plt.plot(sizes,list_times_loop,label='loop on array')
plt.plot(sizes,list_times_instantiate_list,label='instantiate list')
plt.xlabel('sizes of array')
plt.ylabel('time (µs)')
plt.ylim(0,1.4e7)
plt.legend(fontsize=7.5)

plt.plot(sizes,np.array(list_times_create_random_randint_set)/np.array(list_times_compute_mean),label='ratio "randint from [1,size] with shape (50,)" over mean')
plt.plot(sizes,np.array(list_times_create_random_randint_size)/np.array(list_times_compute_mean),label='ratio "randint from [1,50] with shape (size,)" over mean')
plt.plot(sizes,np.array(list_times_create_random_rand)/np.array(list_times_compute_mean),label='ratio "random array with shape (size,)" over mean')
plt.plot(sizes,np.array(list_times_create_random_uniform)/np.array(list_times_compute_mean),label='ratio "uniform random array from (0,1) with shape (size,)" over mean')
plt.plot(sizes,np.array(list_times_create_random_choice)/np.array(list_times_compute_mean),label='ratio "pick randomly 1 value from array with shape (size,)" over mean')
plt.plot(sizes,np.array(list_times_compute_sqared_values)/np.array(list_times_compute_mean),label='ratio compute sqared array over mean')
plt.plot(sizes,np.array(list_times_loop)/np.array(list_times_compute_mean),label='ratio loop on array over mean')
plt.plot(sizes,np.array(list_times_instantiate_list)/np.array(list_times_compute_mean),label='ratio loop on array over mean')
plt.xlabel('sizes of array')
plt.ylabel('how many times slower than mean')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend(fontsize=7.5)

plt.hlines(y=50,xmin=0,xmax=1e9,linestyle='dashed',color='pink')
plt.text(s=50,x=-1.1e8,y=50)
plt.hlines(y=4.5,xmin=0,xmax=1e9,linestyle='dashed',color='red')
plt.text(s=4.5,x=-1.1e8,y=4.5)
plt.hlines(y=2,xmin=0,xmax=1e9,linestyle='dashed',color='grey')
plt.text(s=2,x=-1.1e8,y=2)
plt.hlines(y=8,xmin=0,xmax=1e9,linestyle='dashed',color='orange')
plt.text(s=8,x=-4e7,y=8)
plt.hlines(y=0.3,xmin=0,xmax=1e9,linestyle='dashed',color='blue')
plt.text(s=0.3,x=-1.1e8,y=0.3)
```

Here is the evolution of the computation time in microseconds for the 4 operations "mean", "square", "for loop" and "random number generation".

[image]

And see below the evolution of these computational time normalized by the time of the "mean" operation. On can see that assuming that the mean operation is said to be "1 time unit", then the squared operation is 1.5, the random generation is 4.5 and the for loop is 50.

[image]